# Связь нового контролера с новой View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Я подключил базу данных через EF. Всё хорошо я попробовал поработать с ней. Но т.к. у меня несколько таблиц я захотел разделить контролеры и View часть на соответственные таблицы. Что бы не захламлять всё в 1. Я попытался сделать это на 1 таблице и потерпел крах. Вот что я пытался:
У меня есть соответственно база и я взял для попыток таблицу Models. Создал View, и контроллер:

[image: Файлы проекта]
Далее я попытался добавить Route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Models",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/id",
            defaults: new { controller = "Models", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
```

И в _Layout я пытался вызвать стартовую страницу Index из Models:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Models", "Index", "Models")</li>
```

Так же я создал соответственные контроллеры:
из ModelsController:

```
// GET: Models
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Models.ToList());
        }
```

Но естественно получаю ошибку..
Где Я жестко ошибся, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: ошибка то какая? и вообще то принято вью-модели разделять от dto

Comment: @Konst, в данный момент ничего не меняя получаю: `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`

Comment: посмотрите этот пример: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1105184/ASP-NET-MVC-Building-Your-First-Web-Application-Pa

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ); оставьте только это маршрут, проверьте как будет работать с указанием контроллера и действия в урл. маршруты проверяются от самого первого до последнего по порядку

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо переименовать папку Models в View. Т.к. конфликт папок(не удачное название таблицы из бд)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Models", "Index", "Название папки с View")</li>
```